# Using two windows 10 installs on two partition with one key?

Tags: windows, desktop-computer, windows-10-v1703

So I have a standard OEM PC with Windows 10 installed. I have my main partition I use for dev and editing work. I don't want to install the new "Creator's Update" on that partition but I was curious if I could install and try the Creator's update on a new  partition without having to buy a second windows key.

Thanks!
Derek

Comment: Any new Windows installation can be installed on a 30-day trial. If you install new using your current key, I can't see an ethical problem, since you will never run both installations at the same time, but I can't say if it's strictly legal, though the licensing system may not distinguish between the two installations, since the hardware profile is identical.

Comment: In the same system means there won't be any problem i think so.